# jquery for select all item in multiple select list box

Tags: jquery

Jquery for select all item in multiply select list box.

```
$("#pl_new").find("option").each(function() {
     $(this).attr('selected', true);
});
```

This is not work to select all item in list box when form submitted.

Comment: That would work fine, if you were using a normal select element with the multiple attribute. Please provide your html and any code/plugins that interact with said html. (though, you likely should be using `.prop`, not `.attr`) working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tusUA/

Comment: Also you can avoid looping through just do `$("#pl_new").children("option").prop('selected', true);`

Comment: FWIW, `$('#pl_new option').prop('selected', true)` should do exactly the same as the above code.

Comment: Yes, it would be better if you can provide some more code, so that we can properly guide you...

Comment: $("#pl_new").children("option").prop('selected', true);
$('#pl_new option').prop('selected', true);
all workinggggggg.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### jQuery code:

You need to be using

```
$(this).prop('selected', true);
```

But if you still wanna use `attr()` then use this:

```
$(this).attr('selected', 'selected'); // your method is also OK!
```

#### Select `multiple` attribute:

P.S, please check that whether the `select` tag has the `multiple` attribute in it or not ;) since that might be the cause of the problem.

Since in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/tusUA/1/ by Kevin, you can see the `multiple` attribute applied to the `select` and the code is working.

Comment: @KevinB, I have editted the question, to explain two possible errors in the code, 1. `multiple` attribute and 2. `prop` and `attr` usage..